# How to Write a Unix Shell to Sum the Values in a Row Against Each Unique Column (e.g., how to calculate total votes for each distinct candidate)

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

In its basic form, I am given a text file with state vote results from the 2012 Presidential Election and I need to write a one line shell script in Unix to determine which candidate won. The file has various fields, one of which is CandidateName and the other is TotalVotes. Each record in the file is the results from one precinct within the state, thus there are many records for any given CandidateName, so what I'd like to be able to do is sort the data according to CandidateName and then ultimately sum the TotalVotes for each unique CandidateName (so the sum starts at a unique CandidateName and ends before the next unique CandidateName).

Comment: Can you please post an excerpt of your input file and what the expect result is ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for sorting with `awk` and its associative arrays.  For convenience, the data file format can be:

```
precinct1:candidate name1:732
precinct1:candidate2 name:1435
precinct2:candidate name1:9920
precinct2:candidate2 name:1238
```

Thus you need to create totals of field 3 based on field 2 with `:` as the delimiter.

```
awk -F: '{sum[$2] += $3} END { for (name in sum) { print name " = " sum[name] } }' data.file
```

Some versions of `awk` can sort internally; others can't.  I'd use the sort program to process the results:

```
sort -t= -k2nb
```

(field separator is the `=` sign; the sort is on field 2, which is a numeric field, possibly with leading blanks).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite one line, but will work

```
$ cat votes.txt
Colorado  Obama     50
Colorado  Romney    20
Colorado  Gingrich  30
Florida   Obama     60
Florida   Romney    20
Florida   Gingrich  30
```

script

```
while read loc can num
do
  if ! [ ${!can} ]
  then
    cans+=($can)
  fi
  (( $can += num ))
done < votes.txt
for can in ${cans[*]}
do
  echo $can ${!can}
done
```

output

```
Obama 110
Romney 40
Gingrich 60
```